# Как создать корпоративный сайт со своим дизайном используя SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Мне необходимо сделать корпоративный сайт по макету, использую при этом Office 365 Online (или SharePoint Server 2013) и SharePoint Designer 2013 (последнее опционально).
Абсолютно никакого опыта работы с SharePoint до этого не имел и даже не слышал о нем (и вообще, я еще студент).

Всё, что на нем необходимо реализовать - это новостную ленту и галерею (очевидно, с нормальным добавлением, а не через код). Дизайн макета не представляет собой ничего сложного, основная проблема - SharePoint.

Если вы встречали подробные (с рассчетом на нулевые знания по SharePoint'у) текстовые или видео уроки (туториалы) (хотя бы на английском языке), то буду крайне благодарен вашей наводке.

PS Дело в том, что, после создания сайта, в настройках можно выбрать оформление, однако там нету функции загрузки или создания своего дизайна. Отсюда и возникает данный вопрос. Как же создать свой дизайн для SharePoint?

Спасибо!

Comment: оговорюсь сразу делать порталы на SharePoint не довелось но краткий поиск в инете дал следующее: Дизайн портала можно сделать свой использую CSS(т.е. пишем свой файл стилей) надеюсь помог в задании вектора движения. успехов

Comment: [почитай у Плотникова](https://dplotnikov.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/sharepoint-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3/), информация доступно изложена, в свое время очень помогла на первых порах.

Answer (score 3):

Сходу взять и поменять дизайн в SharePoint будет нелегко, Вам надо будет изучить архитектуру SharePoint. Я рекомендую книгу **"Pro SharePoint 2013 Branding and Responsive Web Development"**, в ней есть все необходимые данные для смены дизайна. Еще рекомендую править не существующие мастер-страницы, а использовать "стартовые", в них есть очень полезные комментарии. Скачать можно [здесь](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/).
Еще есть одна сложность, исходя из которой Вам хорошо бы было знать как работает ASP.NET Web Forms. Не MVC. Смысл в том, что редактируя мастер страницу вы не увидите часть HTML, который будете видеть в браузере. Это связано с тем, что в ASP.NET есть такое понятие как "контрол", он декларативно вставляется в мастер-страницу и по ходу выполнения генерирует HTML. Но некоторые контролы можно настраивать, документация есть на MSDN. Так же в SharePoint есть "темы", вы можете править существующие или создавать свои, они нужны в основном для управления фоновым изображением и цветовыми схемами. Они, кстати, соответствуют формату цветовых схем в Microsoft Office Power Point.
Так же в SharePoint есть инструмент для создания мастер-страниц на основе готовых html макетов, подробнее [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/jj822370.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).